# how to find distinct record using Join in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, join, inner-join, distinct-values

I have to table One is for User and second is  Image. There are many row in Image table for Same Uid.   How to find distinct record according to Uid.

```
User 
ID , int
Date Date

Image 
ImageID int
ImageStatus int
Uid  int  (reference from  User Table)
ImagePath varchar(50)
```

i am using below query but its giving more than one row for UId

```
select I.Uid, I.ImagePath, I.status from user u inner join Image I on u.Uid=I.Uid  order by u.Date desc
```

Comment: can you provide data and what you want to get as the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Row_number()` with `Partition`

```
;with cte as
(
select I.Uid, I.ImagePath,rn=row_number()over(partition by I.Uid order by u.Date desc), I.status from user u inner join Image I on u.Uid=I.Uid
)

select * from cte where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do the join but instead can find the distinct UID in image table.

```
select distinct I.Uid from Image I;
```

Or if you want to list the specific columns distinctly:

```
select distinct I.Uid, I.ImagePath, I.status from Image I order by u.Date desc;
```

Comment: @kapildevsharma : try below one!